# Usando switch i18n, evitar perder idioma seleccionado al refrescar o cambiar de view

Tags: javascript, html, i18n, localización

buen día, tengo un problema, estoy usando **"JavaScript Localization"**, para una web, pero tengo un problema, no encuentro como evitar que el **DOM** deje de priorizar el idioma local del navegador y tome el del switch como referencia al hacer cambio o refresh de view, estoy tratando de no usar **NPM** ni nada de ello, **javascript** puro.

Pongamos de ejemplo, mi navegador esta en **ES-Español**, pero decido cambiar con el switch a **EN-Inglés**, lo selecciono y se cambia automáticamente, ahí todo bien, pero cambio de view y se reinicia al idioma de mi navegador, que era **ES-Español**.

*Los **idiomas** los agarra de json's locales.*

```js
// The locale our app first shows
const defaultLocale = "en";
const supportedLocales = ["en", "es", "1"];

// The active locale
let locale;

// Gets filled with active locale translations
let translations = {};

// When the page content is ready...
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Translate the page to the default locale
  const initialLocale = supportedOrDefault(browserLocales(true));
  
  
  setLocale(initialLocale);

  bindLocaleSwitcher(initialLocale);
});

function isSupported(locale) {
  return supportedLocales.indexOf(locale) > -1;
}

// Retrieve the first locale we support from the given
// array, or return our default locale
function supportedOrDefault(locales) {
  return locales.find(isSupported) || defaultLocale;
}

function browserLocales(languageCodeOnly = false) {
  return navigator.languages.map((locale) =>
  languageCodeOnly ? locale.split("-")[0] : locale,
  );
}

// Whenever the user selects a new locale, we
// load the locale's translations and update
// the page
function bindLocaleSwitcher(initialValue) {
  const switcher = document.querySelector("[data-i18n-switcher]");
  switcher.value = initialValue;
  switcher.onchange = (e) => {
    // Set the locale to the selected option[value]
    setLocale(e.target.value);
  };
}

/**
 * Retrieve user-preferred locales from the browser
 *
 * @param {boolean} languageCodeOnly - when true, returns
 * ["en", "fr"] instead of ["en-US", "fr-FR"]
 * @returns array | undefined
 */

// Load translations for the given locale and translate
// the page to this locale
async function setLocale(newLocale) {
  if (newLocale === locale) return;
  const newTranslations = 
    await fetchTranslationsFor(newLocale);
  locale = newLocale;
  translations = newTranslations;
  translatePage();
}

// Retrieve translations JSON object for the given
// locale over the network
async function fetchTranslationsFor(newLocale) {
  const response = await fetch(`/lang/${newLocale}.json`);
  return await response.json();
}

// Replace the inner text of each element that has a
// data-i18n-key attribute with the translation corresponding
// to its data-i18n-key
function translatePage() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll("[data-i18n-key]")
    .forEach(translateElement);
}

// Replace the inner text of the given HTML element
// with the translation in the active locale,
// corresponding to the element's data-i18n-key
function translateElement(element) {
  const key = element.getAttribute("data-i18n-key");
  const translation = translations[key];
  element.innerText = translation;
}
```

```css
.locale-switcher {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    height: 32px;
    border-color: rgb(197, 197, 197);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.locale-switcher option{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.languageNav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
/* Style the links inside the sidenav */
#mySidenav a {
    position: fixed; /* Position them relative to the browser window */
    right: 0px; /* Position them outside of the screen */
    transition: 0.4s; /* Add transition on hover */
    padding: 15px; /* 15px padding */
    width: 240px; /* Set a specific width */
    text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline */
    font-size: 20px; /* Increase font size */
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 99999;
  }
  #mySidenav img {
    filter: invert();
    transform: scale(1.2);
    margin-right: 13px;
  }
  #mySidenav:focus { 
      outline: none; 
  }
  
  /* The about link: 20px from the top with a green background */
  #about {
    top: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a id="about" >
                <select id="switch_i18n" data-i18n-switcher class="locale-switcher" style="width: fit-content;">
                    <option value="en">English</option>
                    <option value="es">Español</option>
                    <option value="1" >Es_Castellano</option>
                </select>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar localStorage o sessionStorage para que permanezca el cambio en tu navegador de este modo:

En la función supportedOrDefault()

```
function supportedOrDefault(locales) {
  if (typeof localStorage.getItem('language') !== 'undefined' && localStorage.getItem('language') !== null) {
    return localStorage.getItem('language');
  } else {
    return locales.find(isSupported) || defaultLocale;
  }
}
```

Y en la función bindLocaleSwitcher()

```
function bindLocaleSwitcher(initialValue) {
  const switcher = document.querySelector("[data-i18n-switcher]");
  switcher.value = initialValue;
  switcher.onchange = (e) => {
    localStorage.setItem('language', e.target.value)
    // Set the locale to the selected option[value]
    setLocale(e.target.value);
  };
}
```

### Cambios realizados

- En la función supportedOrDefault() se ha agregado un condicional que comprueba si existe previamente la variable almacenada en la clave **language** del `localStorage`, y si existe la usamos para definir el idioma durante la carga de la página en lugar de comprobar si el idioma del navegador esta soportado o pasarle el idioma por defecto.
- En la función bindLocaleSwitcher() se ha agregado esta línea:

```
localStorage.setItem('language', e.target.value)
```

la cual crea o actualiza el valor almacenado en la clave `language` del **localStorage** y que permanecerá en el navegador del cliente aunque cambie de página dentro del mismo dominio.